# R - Predicting on new data in workflow

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

I created a training and test set and tested my model. My workflow looks at follows:

```
# Test/train 
set.seed(2402) ## This generates a random order
splits <- initial_split(Data, prop = 0.7) ## 70% will be training data

# Create a train and test set
Data_train <- training(splits)
Data_test <- testing(splits)
```

```
# Specify the recipe
rf_mod <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = 200) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation")
```

```
# Create a workflow
rf_mod_workflow <-  workflow() %>%
  add_model(rf_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(rf_mod_recipe) 
rf_mod_workflow
```

```
# State our error metrics
class_metrics <- metric_set(rmse, mae)
```

Make the computation faster by registerDoParallel()

```
registerDoParallel()
```

```
rf_grid <- grid_regular(
  mtry(range = c(5, 15)),
  min_n(range = c(10, 200)),
  levels = 5
)

rf_grid
```

```
set.seed(654321)

rf_tune_res <- tune_grid(
  rf_mod_workflow,
  resamples = cv_folds,
  grid = rf_grid,
  metrics = class_metrics
)

# Select the best number of mtry
best_rmse <- select_best(rf_tune_res, "rmse")
rf_final_wf <- finalize_workflow(rf_mod_workflow, best_rmse)
rf_final_wf

# Finalise the workflow
set.seed(56789)
rf_final_fit <- rf_final_wf %>%
  last_fit(splits, metrics = class_metrics)
```

However, I now want to use my created model to predict on a new dataset. The problem is that this new dataset contains NA values. Is it still possible to predict on a dataset that has NA values, or does the random forest not allow it? I did something similar for a linear regression and that one ignored the NA values and only predicted for instances where no NA values are present.

Answer (score 1):

If ignoring `NA`s is fine for you, just remove them from your new data. Assuming your new data is a dataframe called `newdata`, you can get the indices of rows with at least one `NA`-value as folows

```
naRowIndices <- rowSums(is.na(newdata)) >= 1
newNonNaData <- newdata[!naRowIndices ,]
```

Then do the prediction `newNonNaPredictions <- ...predict newNonNaData...`. Now you have your predicitons on the data without `NA`s. If you need your predicition output of the same length as the original data with `NA`s, you need padding like:

```
newPrediction <- rep(NA,NROW(newdata))
newPrediction[!naRowIndices] <- newNonNaPredictions
```